# Conditional expression on putItem

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

i am trying to check if key exist on table before making putItem operation on dynamodb to prevent overriding existing key value

Comment: Why you have asked this question, if you already know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
PutItemExpressionSpec PUT_ITEM_EXPRESSION_SPEC = new ExpressionSpecBuilder()
           .withCondition(ExpressionSpecBuilder.S("uuid").notExists())
           .buildForPut();

// create item

PutItemSpec putItemSpec = new PutItemSpec()
                .withItem(item)
                .withExpressionSpec(PUT_ITEM_EXPRESSION_SPEC); // Checking if UUID exists on the Table
// get Table
table.putItem(putItemSpec);
```